# dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure): installed mysql-server-8.0

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dpkg, ubuntu-22.04

when I tried to install Mysql in Ubuntu 22.04, but it failed! I tried with many solutions but none of the solutions worked,
package post-installation script sub-process returned error exit status 1
need restart is being skipped since dpkg has failed

```
Jun 10 19:13:39 ip-172-31-9-200 systemd[1]: mysql.service: A process of this unit has been killed by the OOM killer.
Jun 10 19:13:39 ip-172-31-9-200 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Jun 10 19:13:39 ip-172-31-9-200 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Jun 10 19:13:39 ip-172-31-9-200 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.54-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.